# Intuitive proof of surface area of a sphere in relation to area of great circle using shadow.

Tags: geometry, circles, area, spheres

I'm trying to show my kids intuitive proofs of common formulas, and watched this excellent video from 3Blue1Brown: [But why is a sphere's surface area four times its shadow?](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GNcFjFmqEc8)
However, I didn't find the 'shadow' explanation intuitive (or I misunderstood it), and came up with an alternative, though I'm quite sure it's been thought before.

Take a sphere and cut it and half leaving a dome, and illuminate it from above.

Split the dome into equal horizontal rings, and note that each ring shades the 'ground' using some percentage of it's surface.  For the ring at the top of the dome, the shadow will be 100% of the surface of the ring, whereas for the ring at the ground the shadow will be 0% of the surface, since the ring is edge-on to the light.

Since the dome is completely symmetrical we can take the 'average' shadow factor as 50%. Therefore the surface area of the dome is twice the area of the great circle, and the full sphere is 4 times.

Is there a formal proof of this idea, and what is it called, or is it just a coincidence, and which part(s) of the argument are wrong?

Comment: The result you are told is a special case of "Cauchy's Surface area formula" (try to use this a search key on google). The statement is true not only for sphere but for all convex bodies. Loosely speacking, the "angular average" of the area of shadow of any convex bodies (in $\mathbb{R}^3$) is $\frac14$ of its surface area.

Comment: @achillehui I tried reading https://arxiv.org/pdf/1604.05815.pdf. My naive understanding says $\mu_{n-1}(\mathbb{B}^{n}|u^{\perp})=\mu_{n-1}(\mathbb{B}^{n-1})$ and thus the terms cancel leaving $S(\mathbb{B}^{n})=\int_{\mathbb{S}^{n-1}}du$. So where does 4 appear?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Since the dome is completely symmetrical we can take the 'average' shadow factor as 50%. Therefore the surface area of the dome is twice the area of the great circle, and the full sphere is 4 times." The issue is justifying that although the range is from $0$ to $100$ that does not necessarily tell us the average is $50$.

Consider the hemisphere in the upper half space centered at the origin with radius $1$. We consider the map from the plane to the hemisphere. Roughly speaking, if we could calculate the average stretch factor, it should be $2$. The disk in the plane with radius $\sqrt{x}$ is $x$ of the area of the disk. The stretch factor at the $\sqrt{x}$ circle is uniformly $\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-x}}$. So averaging the stretch over the portional area gives us $$ \int_0^1\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-x}}dx=2$$

Taking both hemispheres you get $4$ times the area of the disk in the plane. Of course, more work would need to be done to justify this reasoning. Also, I would love an answer without any appeal to calculating an integral.

Comment: "The issue is justifying that although the range is from 0 to 100 that does not necessarily tell us the average is 50."

I can see that is the weakest link, but assumed that because a circle is continuous and symmetric, that would support the argument, though a formal proof might be another matter entirely.
What makes it possible to take an average of a scalar range, etc, formally?  Is it possible to map the two?
I agree it would be very nice to prove it with just 'basic' maths.

Comment: Picking a projection breaks a lot of the symmetry. You lose all but the rotational symmetry on the "z-axis". Formalizing the argument maybe trickier than traditional methods. One major problem is that there is no isometry from an open set of one to the other due to curvature issues.